# Transform connection string depending on data centre for Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, deployment, dns, database-connection, azure-sql-database

I am converting a single data centre .NET app to be geo-distributed. Currently there is one web app running in IIS on a single VM. It connects to a single database server using a connection string in the config.

I already use config transform for dev, UAT and production, which get applied from my build server at deploy time.

In the geo-distributed setup, the web app will be deployed to 2 or more (possibly up to 10) different data centres.

Each data centre will hold geo-replicated Azure SQL databases.

***I need each VM in each data centre to hit the Azure SQL database located in that same data centre.***

I don't want to have to create a configuration in my project for each data centre, specifying a different connection string in each config transform. This is not maintainable or scaleable.

## Example

```
| Data centre      | VM  | DB server                |
| -------------    |-----| -------------------------|
| UK South         | VM1 | db1.database.windows.net |
| South Central US | VM2 | db2.database.windows.net |
| West US          | VM3 | db3.database.windows.net |
| West Europe      | VM4 | db4.database.windows.net |
| ...              | ... | ...                      |
```

As you can see the server name for each db server is different and that is a requirement on Azure SQL. You can't use the same name in different data centres because the name is global.

I haven't been able to find a way to map 1 connection string to each of the above db server names.

Azure Traffic Manager is able to do the geo DNS for you, but Azure SQL demands that you include the server name (db1, db2...) in the connection string (as part of the "server name" or with the "login" e.g. "user@db1").

### What's the best way to approach this? Is my only option to create a config transform for each data centre, or is there another way?

Comment: you can read it from environment variables\vm name, but either way it has to be some sort of mapping, so code can figure out where to get the value from

Comment: @4c74356b41 so do you think I need to tweak how my connection strings are fetched within the app? I.e. don't just pull a plain string from a `.config` file, instead pull a templated string and fill in the blanks using some environment variable on the delivery server? Kinda like using a SQL alias (which SQL Azure doesn't support).

Comment: it doesnt really matter how you construct it, but the fact is, there is nothing built-in so

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any baked in feature that matches up SQL Azure geographically distributed database with a corresponding region to output the correct connection string (I could be wrong). The only geographically aware database I'm aware of (in azure) is CosmosDB.  Instead of writing this type of feature yourself, one that I suspect would be fragile and add overhead, I would suggest approaching it from a different direction.

You mention your build environment. It's very common for the same code to have different settings based on the region it's deployed to and I generally manage these as part of the CI\CD pipeline. When an app gets deployed (via the pipeline) it updates the setting for that region as part of the deployment to that specific region.  If you deploy to new regions you simply update your CI\CD with the correct connection string. Same rules apply to dev\stage etc.  Manage the complexity in your build and keep it simple everywhere else.

Comment: can you point me in the direction of any docs/blogs/guidance for doing mult-region deployments like this? We use TeamCity and switch a build param for MSBuild configuration (e.g. debug, staging, release) which has previously been setup within the Visual Studio solution. Are you saying I'd need to create a configuration in the solution for each data centre and create a corresponding build step in Team City for each data center? Or would I use TeamCity to store and vary the connection strings at deploy time whilst still using the "Release" configuration for each region?

Answer (score 0):

I know you've looked into ATM a bit, but this technically can be done with custom urls and Azure Traffic Manager. This should get you around the connection string issues.

Obtain a custom domain and map it an Azure ATM.  Add the four database urls to the ATM as external endpoints and you should have enough info for the Azure SQL connection string; if you do an nslookup on the custom ATM url, you'll see one of your 4 database urls in the Alias list complete with the DB server name.

Caveat Emptor on Geo routing with Azure TM.  It's been wildly inaccurate for me for cases where we don't own the IP.  You could also use Performance routing, but that will not 100% guarantee your going to be routed to the closest DB Server.

Comment: Thanks @jeff. I’ve tried to do this but it seems whatever the sub domain is on the connection string (regardless of the ip it points to) is what needs to match the db server name. Eg db1.mycustomdonain.com will only work if ATM resolves to the ip for db1.database.windows.net. The others will fail. Am I missing something?

Comment: The DB Server url (i.e. db1.database.windows.net) is returned to you and cached locally for whatever your TTL value is (default is 300 seconds). Use that url (rather than the ATM url) to make your db connection.

Comment: But that would require a manual nslookup in the app code rather than just using the connection string as a “normal” connection string, correct?